# Mysql is not running while Apache start in XAMPP

Tags: mysql

when i click to start MySQL it gives this message
Please anybody can help me.Thanks advance.

```
[Tomcat]    Port 8080 in use by ""C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"    -k  runservice"!
[Tomcat]    Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
[Tomcat]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking  application
[Tomcat]    or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a  different port
[main]  Starting Check-Timer
[main]  Control Panel Ready
[mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
[mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
[mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
[mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
```

Comment: and when i click second time to start Mysql it give this message continuously                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   `[mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
[mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...`

Comment: are you using XAMPP?

Comment: @jenisha Makadiya. i following your link but it also give the same error                       **like**                                                                                                                         `[mysql] Attempting to start MySQL app...`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same error,
are you using Skype? If yes, just quit it and then start MySQL. after starting MySQL you can start Skype.

it is due to both apps are using same port.

**else** 
Try Changing ports

this may this link will help you
http://silentlyrun.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-change-apache-n-mysql-port-for.html

Hope this helps you..!

Comment: thanks for response.but it gives the same error after quit skype